# How to reliably find Linux disks in /dev?

Tags: partition

Cross post from https://stackoverflow.com/q/63976722/4534

Previously we used `/dev/[sh]d`? ... but now with the advent of NVMe SSDs /dev/nvme* drives, this is no longer true.

Do you know how to **find install disks**? Or to update the `/dev/[sh]d` match? Or use `/proc/partitions`?

Answer (score 1):

The most surefire way is to traverse `/dev/disk/{by-id,by-label,by-partlabel,by-path,by-uuid}` - I'd personally go for `/dev/disk/by-path`.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore partitions I wonder? https://s.natalian.org/2020-09-20/1600604290_1908x1027.png

Comment: they all end with `-partX` - it's quite simple to filter that out.

Comment: I think this solution assumes udev, right? ```hendry@knuckles ~ $ ls /dev/disk/by-path
ls: cannot access '/dev/disk/by-path': No such file or directory
hendry@knuckles ~ $ uname -a
Linux knuckles 5.8.9_1 #1 SMP Sun Sep 13 20:23:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux```

Comment: I'm not sure what's needed for this but it's here on Fedora 32. And yes, I'm running `systemd-udev`. It's pretty been much a standard for all modern Linux distros for quite some time now.

Comment: Not on Voidlinux

Comment: Voidlinux is a minimalistic Linux distro which cuts corners and tries to reduce its footprint to a bare minimum. I'm surprised they don't export /dev/disk entries but all the major distros have been doing that for the past 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use the `lsblk` command.

```
# list all block devices without paritions
lsblk --nodeps

# to exclude any particular type of block device like optical drives
lsblk --nodeps --exclude 11
```

A full list of block device ids can be found at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt

Comment: No need for another command.  Try `lsblk --nodeps` and optionally `--exclude 9,11` to exclude optical drives and RAM disks. It will only list the block devices without any partitions.

Comment: Thanks @Phoenix . I have updated the answer

Comment: I don’t mean to nitpick, but I believe your update got a typo (or got auto-corrected by your device). You probably meant `lsblk` and not `list` as a command for the exclude example. ;-)

Comment: Thanks once again @Phoenix

Answer (score 0):

From Boot-Repair.

```
All_Hard_Drives=$(ls /dev/hd[a-z] /dev/hd[a-z][a-z] /dev/sd[a-z] /dev/sd[a-z][a-z] /dev/xvd[a-z] /dev/vd[a-z] /dev/vd[a-z][a-z] /dev/nvme[0-9]n[0-9] /dev/nvme[0-9]n[0-9][0-9] /dev/nvme[0-9][0-9]n[0-9] /dev/nvme[0-9][0-9]n[0-9][0-9] /dev/mmcblk[0-9] /dev/mmcblk[0-9][0-9] 2>> ${Trash});
```

Comment: i'm confused by /dev/nvme0 and /dev/nvme0n1 ... what is equivalent to /dev/sda ?

Comment: Note that NVMe devices are named by /dev/nvme[device number]n[namespace number]p[partition number]. General info: https://superuser.com/questions/1535566/confusion-whats-the-difference-between-sata-nvme-m-2-and-pcie & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express#Comparison_with_AHCI

Comment: @hendry `/dev/nvme0n1` is the NVME equivalent of `/dev/sda`, and `/dev/nvme0n1p1` would be the equivalent of `/dev/sda1`. The `n1` part is a NVME namespace ID, which is essentially going to be always `n1` unless you deal with enterprise-grade NVME storage systems. `/dev/nvme0n1` is the device name for `fdisk` and other "whole-disk" access, and you would only use `/dev/nvme0` for things like updating the NVME firmware and some other special operations using the `nvme` command-line tool.

Answer (score 0):

`/sys/block/*`

```
for b in /sys/block/*; do readlink -f $b; done

for b in /sys/block/*; do echo $(cat $b/uevent); done
```

`/sys/class/block/*` if you also want the partitions.

Or:

```
grep -srl DEVTYPE=disk /sys/devices

grep -srl DEVTYPE=partition /sys/devices
```